# EXCEPTION: Error during evaluation of "click"

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular

It is my first steps create angular2 with typescript and i need help.
The first request works well and I'm show it.
When i'm doing click i want to creat a new reqest.
How can i do that?

```
 export class App {
  img: Array<Object>;
  constructor(http:Http) {    http.request('http://boroviha.dev.ooosis.com/api/client/get_photo_sections.php').toRx().subscribe(res => {
      console.log('img',res.json().data);
      this.img = res.json().data;
    });
  }
    onSelect(item: img) { this.selectedItem = item; console.log(item);
     constructor(http:Http) {
     this.http.request('http://localhost:3001/api/random-quote')
        .map(res => res.text())
        .subscribe(
          data => this.randomQuote = data,
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
        );
     }
    }
}
bootstrap(App, [HTTP_BINDINGS, bind(RequestOptions).toClass(MyOptions)])
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define a constructor within the `onSelect` method which is a bit strange:

```
onSelect(item: img) { this.selectedItem = item; console.log(item);
  constructor(http:Http) {
  (...)
```

I woulsd refactor this to something like that:

```
export class App {
  img: Array<Object>;
  constructor(private http:Http) {    
    (...)
  }

  onSelect(item: img) {
    this.selectedItem = item; console.log(item);
    this.http.get('http://localhost:3001/api/random-quote')
        .map(res => res.text())
        .subscribe(
          data => this.randomQuote = data,
          err => this.logError(err),
          () => console.log('Random Quote Complete')
        );
    }
  }
}
```

I added `private` at the level of constructor parameters to make the `http` parameter part of the `App` class. So you can use it with the `this` keyword.

You can notice that now the `HTTP_PROVIDERS` should be used instead of `HTTP_BINDINGS`.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry